# Is 卖掉……事业 correct in 他卖掉了他的事业并且退休, and does it mean "sell [his] business"?

Tags: word-choice

> 他卖掉了他的事业并且退休。
> He sold his business and retired.

The above sentence and translation is from [Tatoeba](https://tatoeba.org/en/sentences/show/848721), but I'm confused as to what it means to 卖掉……事业.

**Question**: Is 卖掉……事业 correct in 他卖掉了他的事业并且退休, and does it mean "sell [his] business"?

We have:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%BA%8B%E4%B8%9A): 事业 (shì​yè​) undertaking / project / activity / (charitable, political or revolutionary) cause / publicly funded institution, enterprise or foundation / career / occupation / CL: 個｜个
>
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%8D%96): 卖 (mài​) to sell / to betray / to spare no effort / to show off or flaunt

The sentence uses 卖掉……事业 to mean "sell [his] business", but it reads like "sell [his] cause".  I'm not sure 事业 is the correct word choice here, since I expect that whatever is 卖掉ed to be a tangible object, like a cake or a house.

Comment: "卖掉……事业 to mean "sell [his] business"" This is correct. I don't see why you'd read it like "sell [his] cause". What if the sentence is changed to "他卖掉了他的事业然後退休"? I believe 並且 is not the best choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

He **sold** his **business** and retired. - 他**卖掉了**他的**生意**同時**(也)**退休了**。

Note the particle "**了**" immediately following the verbs "卖掉(sell)" and "退休(retire)" indicates the completion of the act and actions in the past - 卖掉了 = sold, and 退休了 = retired.

**事业**, for the individual, is a personally chosen career/field of work with a "set goal" (一定目标) that is to be achieved or fulfilled. It shouldn't be confused with works/business for the public good - "慈善事业(charity works)", "教育事业(education business)", or "公用事业(public utilities)".

**Business** - 生意

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, "卖掉……事业 to mean "sell [his] business"" This is correct.

This sentence hints that his career is sellable, like he owns a company, a restranunt and etc,. Some career is not sellable like a programmer, or a work, which can only quit.

@Joehua, 然後 is a good choice if the sentence wants to emphasize the timeline. But 並且 is also great to me if the sentence just want to mention these two events as a description.Sometimes it depends the context.

Answer (score 0):

事業 is "career." Hence it is incorrect to use the term as per the OP

The correct term to use here is 生意 ("business")